# How is the Oculus Touch controller selection implemented?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, virtual-reality, oculus

I'm extremely new to Unity and Oculus, and I'm attempting to follow [this](https://developer.oculus.com/blog/easy-controller-selection/) guide on how to enable a controller laser pointer to select a 3D object in Unity.

This is my current attempt:

- **OVRCameraRig** with components:

  - **OVR Physics Raycaster**
- **EventSystem** with components:

  - **OVR Input Module** (replacing the Standalone Input Module). The OVR Input Module's **Ray Transform** is set to the OVRCameraRig
- **OVR Pointer Visualizer**: *Unable to locate script in Oculus Integration so cannot add*
- **OVR Raw Raycaster**: *Unable to locate script in Oculus Integration so cannot add*
- **OVR Selection Visualizer**: *Unable to locate script in Oculus Integration so cannot add*

My main problem currently is that I am unable to locate the last three assets, even though I am using the latest Oculus Integration package. As well, I get the following error (which may or may not be a result of the missing assets):
`NullReferenceException: UnityEngine.EventSystems.OVRInputModule.GetGazePointerData`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by ray casting forward from controller object - laser and on ray cast hit just do whatever you want with your object, your can also make the same layer what to ray cast trough or to ignore the ones that you don't want to ray cast...